# Window resolution gets screwed up when docking or undocking laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have an HP EliteBook 850 and 2 HP EliteDisplay E231. The laptop has a 14" screen and the monitors are both 23". If I undock the laptop without shutting down first, the resolution of the windows get's screwed up. I've double checked the screen resolution and it is does not change from 1920x1080, but the application windows all appear to be scaled to a screen whose resolution has been set to 1600x900.

Alternatively, if I am using the laptop and then attach it to the docking station, the windows appear very small on the main monitors. When I drag windows between the laptop screen and the main screens I can see them change size.

I've already tried updating my video driver, but the problem persists. The only way to fix it is to restart the laptop. This is driving me crazy! Does anyone have any ideas?